# How to make sure each Minitest unit test is fast enough?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a large amount of Minitest unit tests (methods), over 300. They all take some time, from a few milliseconds to a few seconds. Some of them hang up, sporadically. I can't understand which one and when.

I want to apply `Timeout` to each of them, to make sure anyone fails if it takes longer than, say, 5 seconds. Is it achievable?

For example:

```
class FooTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_calculates_something
    # Something potentially too slow
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post an example of such a test and the method it tests?

Comment: @spickermann updated the question

Comment: This sounds like a xy question to me. Why do you try to hack a work around instead of investigating why the test are flacky and fix the tests?

Comment: @yegor256 Can you please provide some more meaningful context in the example? *What* are you testing, that takes 5 seconds? Perhaps there is a better way to investigate/fix what's running so slowly, instead of auto-failing all tests that take too long.

Comment: If the issue is that you "can't figure out which test is freezing", then perhaps we should focus on that? There are various strategies you could employ to track down the root of the problem (without a global `Timeout` wrapper, which may not even work).

Comment: @TomLord appreciate your willingness to help, but I do need a generic solution, to timeout __any__ test that is slower than 5 seconds.

Comment: @yegor256 Have you tried using https://github.com/splattael/minitest-around or https://github.com/jeremyevans/minitest-hooks? Or perhaps a better way to diagnose this would be with https://github.com/nmeans/minitest-profile?

Comment: @TomLord minitest-hooks was exactly what I was looking for. If you make it an answer, I will choose it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Minitest PLugin loader to load a plugin. This is, by far, the cleanest solution. The plugin system is not very well documented, though.

Luckily, Adam Sanderson wrote [an article on the plugin system](http://www.monkeyandcrow.com/blog/reading_ruby_minitest_plugin_system/).

The best news is that this article explains the plugin system by writing a sample plugin that *reports* slow tests. Try out [minitest-snail](https://github.com/adamsanderson/minitest-snail), it is probably almost what you want.

With a little modification we can use the `Reporter` to mark a test as failed if it is too slow, like so (untested):

File `minitest/snail_reporter.rb`:

```
module Minitest
  class SnailReporter < Reporter
    attr_reader :max_duration

    def self.options
      @default_options ||= {
        :max_duration => 2
      }
    end

    def self.enable!(options = {})
      @enabled = true
      self.options.merge!(options)
    end

    def self.enabled?
      @enabled ||= false
    end

    def initialize(io = STDOUT, options = self.class.options)
      super
      @max_duration = options.fetch(:max_duration)
    end

    def record result
      @passed = result.time < max_duration
      slow_tests << result if !@passed
    end

    def passed?
      @passed
    end

    def report
      return if slow_tests.empty?

      slow_tests.sort_by!{|r| -r.time}

      io.puts
      io.puts "#{slow_tests.length} slow tests."
      slow_tests.each_with_index do |result, i|
        io.puts "%3d) %s: %.2f s" % [i+1, result.location, result.time]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

File `minitest/snail_plugin.rb`:

```
require_relative './snail_reporter'

module Minitest
  def self.plugin_snail_options(opts, options)
    opts.on "--max-duration TIME", "Report tests that take longer than TIME seconds." do |max_duration|
      SnailReporter.enable! :max_duration => max_duration.to_f
    end
  end

  def self.plugin_snail_init(options)
    if SnailReporter.enabled?
      io = options[:io]
      Minitest.reporter.reporters << SnailReporter.new(io)
    end
  end

end
```